# upstart log directory has no log files just compressed files

Tags: upstart, log, fsck

using 16.04, it kept running fsck on boot-up. So I tried to find where all the fsck logs might be. Another askUbuntu thread suggested **/var/log/upstart/mountall.log**

But when I looked in /var/log/upstart/ there was no log files, only compressed files. It seems to be the case for all other types of log files in there. Even the compressed files only few bytes in size and can not be opened.

There seems to be a bug which covers this

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/upstart/+bug/1350782

Is there any way to get it to write to log

Comment: I upgraded from 14.04 LTS, the syslog file is empty nothing there.  does systemd log files, does it handle fsck logs

Comment: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-fsck@.service.html

Comment: that link has no info on where the log file is or how to access it

Comment: See my answer. :-)

Comment: Please open your tune2fs question as a new question as it's more likely to help others as a new question than tagged to the end of this already answered question. In this way we can be more efficient and help as many people as possible. For this reason I'm rolling back this question to what it was when it was answered. Thank you understanding.

Answer (score 2):

16.04 doesn't use [upstart anymore](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/what-s-new-in-ubuntu-16-04) by default so unless you've done something clever, you are using systemd and you are likely looking at files left over from a previous version due to an upgrade rather than clean install.

If fsck has run recently on  a non-root partition on yourr system you can confirm this by running `grep fsck /var/log/syslog`

Which in my case results in:

```
Mar 22 15:06:27 64bitUbuntu systemd-fsck[750]: /dev/sdb1: clean, 146223/121454592 files, 356711795/485818368 blocks
```

In 16.04 You can find what you seek in the file `/var/log/boot.log`

Here's an example from my 16.04 system created at last boot:

The boot fsck results are stored in `var/log/boot.log`

```
ll /var/log/boot.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 96 Mar 22 15:06 /var/log/boot.log


Scanning for Btrfs filesystems
/dev/sda2: clean, 349091/1954064 files, 2379983/7814912 blocks
```

Sources:

https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-fsck@.service.html

`ls /var/log`

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you see the same using `journalctl -u systemd-fsckd`?

Comment: syslog is empty,  bootl.log doesn't have the results of the fsck just only
 /dev/sda1: clean, 313673/673296 files, 2020820/2687988 blocks, checking tunefs it's not updating the last checked date

Comment: @steeldriver that command reports when the file system check daemon was started, so no.